# How to inspect particular DHCP server response by IP (linux)?

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp, sniffing

I have following setup:

```
ISP -> junk-isp-router -> MikroTik RB2011 -> ...
```

Yesterday I enabled rogue DHCP server alerting on RB2011 and today I received alert that it somehow got DHCP response packet from ISP DHCP server. I think it's caused by derpy DMZ implementation on junk router which seems to improperly forward DHCP packets to DMZ host instead of accepting them.

Junk router has disabled DHCP server. RB2011 has no DHCP client. Is there any way to manually query that server and see what is its response? I know its IP address. MAC is obviously invalid because it's MAC of junk router.

Comment: "RB2011 has no DHCP client" Really? What version of RouterOS lacks a DHCP client?

Comment: https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:IP/DHCP_Client for routeros. However if you want to do a manual query to capture packets for later inspection, you could do that from a linux box using dhclient: https://linux.die.net/man/8/dhclient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to inspect particular DHCP server response by IP (linux)?

tcpdump -i eth0 -w log.pcap -n "src net 1.2.3.4/18 or 9.8.7.6/20"

Will log all traffic and/or you can apply filters like source,destination, ip, port, and etc.  Then inspect the result in wireshark.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question. He asked specifically how to manually form a DHCP query in order to generate a response that he could then inspect.